# My N Queen Problem works up until n = 5 and I don't know why C++

Tags: c++, n-queens

I'm still fairly new to coding so take it easy but I'm working on the N Queen problem which calls for the amount of solutions for a board of n size where you can place a queen on every row. My code works up to n=4 and then n=5 outputs 11 and all n's after output 0. -1s appear in placements[] up to n=5 and then they aren't input into the array afterwards. I'm pretty clueless now so some help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//MAXROWS is same as MAXCOLUMNS or BOARDSIZE
const int MAXROWS = 20;

//queens' placements in each row
int placements[MAXROWS];
int n = 0;
int solutionsCount = 0;

bool canPlaceQueen(int row, int column)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < row; j++)
        if((placements[j] == column) // is there a queen in same column?
            || (abs(placements[j] - column) == abs(j-row))) // checks diagonals
            return false;           // column difference is same as row difference?

    return true;
}

bool correctSolution()
{
   
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        if (placements[i] == placements[j])
        {
            return false;
        }
   }
   
   for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
   {
      if (placements[k] == -1)
      {
         return false;
      }
   }
   
   return true;
}

void placeQueens(int row) {
    //try to place queen in each column in current row
    //then continue to explore: placeQueens(row+1)
    //for each successful queen placement in final row, increment solutionsCount!
    
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
      if (canPlaceQueen(row, i))
      {
         placements[row] = i;
         if (row < n-1)
         {
            placeQueens(row+1);
         }
      }
      else
      {
         placements[row] = -1;
      }
      
      if (correctSolution())
      {
         solutionsCount++;
         cout << "add" << placements[0] << placements [1] << placements[2] << placements[3] << endl;
      }
         
   } 
   
   cout << "new" << placements[0] << placements [1] << placements[2] << placements[3] << endl;
    
    
   for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
   {
      placements[j] = 0;
   }
}

int main() {
    cout << "Enter the board size: ";
    cin >> n;

    placeQueens(0);
    cout << "Number of solutions: " << solutionsCount << endl;
}
```

Comment: I don't think correctSolution() works. The placement array tells you which column the queen is on for a row. Imagine n=8. If you have a queen on (0,0) ie placements[0] = 0 and a queen on (7,7), ie placements[7] = 7, then placements[0] is != to placements[7], but yet it's an invalid solution (two queens on the same diagonal). Your check only checks if two queens are on the same column. Actually I think you could have the entire diagonal filled with queens and it'd still pass the check.

Comment: I did this problem in scheme a few weeks ago. My recursive strategy was to start in the nth column and find the list of solutions for n-1 columns (the recursive step). Then I took each of those solutions and generated a new potential solution by putting a queen on row 0 in column n and checking it, changing the queen to row 1 and check it again etc. only keeping the ones that work out. Say the grid is 8x8, so the function starts with column 7, so it needs the solutions for only 6 columns (but still 7 rows!), which in turn needs the solutions for 5 columns etc, recurses its way down and back.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you and your endeavors, sport!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//MAXROWS is same as MAXCOLUMNS or BOARDSIZE
const int MAXROWS = 20;

//queens' placements in each row
int placements[MAXROWS];
int n = 0;
int solutionsCount = 0;

bool canPlaceQueen(int row, int column)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < row; j++)
        if ((placements[j] == column)                         // is there a queen in same column?
            || (abs(placements[j] - column) == abs(j - row))) // checks diagonals
            return false;                                     // column difference is same as row difference?

    return true;
}

void placeQueens(int row)
{
    //try to place queen in each column in current row
    //then continue to explore: placeQueens(row+1)
    //for each successful queen placement in final row, increment solutionsCount!

    if (row == n) //If the last row has been reached then there is a solution
    {
        solutionsCount++; //incrementing the solution count
        return;           //returning back
    }

    for (int column = 1; column <= n; column++) // To check all the columns from 1 to n
    {
        if (canPlaceQueen(row, column) == true)
        {
            placements[row] = column; //placing the queen in Row row on Column column

            placeQueens(row + 1); //calling the next row

            placements[row] = 0; //removing the queen from this column
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter the board size: ";
    cin >> n;

    placeQueens(0);

    cout << "Number of solutions: " << solutionsCount << endl;
}
```

Sincerely,

Mike